# How to add AWS Virtual Machine to Azure Active Directory Domain?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

I need to understand whether is it possible to add AWS Virtual machine to custom domain controller of Azure.

I have created Active Directory Domain controller in one of the Virtual machine of Azure. Now I have created few virtual machines on AWS (Amazon Web Services). I want to add these machines into Azure custom Domain controller.

Is it possible and if yes, then can someone please guide me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with AWS now, but you could try and create a Site-to-Site VPN and test, most likely will not work, but who knows, you might try to replicate your Azure VM DNS network configuration on your AWS VM and see if it helps.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-networking) the networking guide for Azure AD Services.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested joining Linux VMs across a Site to Site VPN and they work OK (it was to Azure Active Directory Domain Services, machines could join and users log on).

As the above answer notes however DNS is the killer here.  With the Linux boxes I was able to use local config files to save needing to replicate the DNS zone, for Windows boxes you could try hacking the hosts file with some #pre #dom entries but in reality I think you would need a zone replica in your AWS DNS servers for it to work reliably.